# What could be the cause for Socket errors reported by JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, socketexception

I am running a test with 350 users at peak. I have split the tests in two machine with one machine running 220 users and rest on the other machine. On both the machines after a few minutes of run I start seeing socket exception, socket time-out exception and HTTP host exception.

I have tried to find any error that correlates to this exception in the load-balancer (software), IIS logs, application logs and environment monitoring system but I have not found them any where.

I read a lot of blogs and answers on SO that have had the same problem and were able to solve it through changing JMeter settings. I have attempted all of these settings but none have helped.

I am running my test on

```
Windows Server 2012 R2/ 6 GB RAM/ 64 Bit OS/ 64 bit Java/ Intel Xeon CPU E5-46170 @ 2.90 GHz processor/ JMeter 2.13
```

My JMeter.bat setting are:

```
set HEAP=-Xms1536m -Xmx2048m
set NEW=-XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
set SURVIVOR=-XX:SurvivorRatio=3 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=50%
set TENURING=-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=12
rem Java 8 remove Permanent generation, don't settings the PermSize
if %current_minor% LEQ "8" (
    rem Increase MaxPermSize if you use a lot of Javascript in your Test Plan :
    set PERM=-XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
)

set IPV4=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
set ARGS=%DUMP% %HEAP% %NEW% %SURVIVOR% %TENURING% %RMIGC% %PERM% %DDRAW% %IPV4%
```

My HC.Parameter settings are:

```
http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
```

My user.properties settings are:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true

httpclient4.retrycount=1
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
```

I am running my test for 2 hours and my test have been set to loop forever, Stop Thread on error (also run using: start next thread loop on error). I have checked Download Embedded resources and have set the connection Pool as 6(also run with 4).

I have run the tests using default HTTP client and HTTPClient 4.

As of now I can think of 3 other things to try but I am pretty much at the end of my wits and could use a few suggestions.

1. IP Spoofing,
2. Run with Java Client
3. Run in Server client mode.

If you need additional information i'll provide as much as I can but please help!

**Additional information:**

*Socket errors I am getting*

```
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$6: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$6: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

*Directly hitting IIS*
I ran some tests by directly hitting one server with Failed request logging turned on and noticed the below errors.

```
A process serving application pool 'XXXXXXXXX' failed to respond to a ping.
The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP XXXXXXXXXXXXXX with exit code 80131506.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load test, it happens very often that application under test cannot handle the load which will manifest as socket rest, socket timeout...

In your case the server is closing the connection, this means it's probably overloaded.
You need to check the components on server side:

- Firewall
- Load Balancer
- Apache or IIS or any other webserver
- J2EE server like tomcat or jboss or other similar

Comment: Added the socket errors I am getting. I agree that it is not a problem with JMeter but there should be corresponding entries for these errors somewhere else but I am not able to find it. Hence asking where else I should be looking or should be doing.

Comment: Firewall - Nothing blocked
Load balancer (software) - Nothing there
IIS - That is the interesting one, nothing obvious logged here. I'll update my question will more details.
No Tomcat,JBoss or anything else - .Net application